# ZK SOAP SDK <GetUserTemplate>

Tags: php, soap, zk, fingerprint

i'm facing little problem here, try to fingerprint Template from ZK based Fingerprint attendance machine.

here's the machine:

```
Welcome to Linux (ZEM510) for MIPS
Kernel 2.4.20 Treckle on an MIPS
ZEM510 login:
```

I wrote getUser.php below:

```
<?php
    include_once 'config.php';
    include_once 'functions.php';

    echo "Contacting Machine...\n";

    $Connect = fsockopen(IP, "80", $errno, $errstr, 1);
    if($Connect) {
        $soap_request="<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><GetAllUserInfo><ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">".KEY."</ArgComKey></GetAllUserInfo></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
        $newLine="\r\n";
        fputs($Connect, "POST /iWsService HTTP/1.0".$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, "Content-Type: text/xml".$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, "Content-Length: ".strlen($soap_request).$newLine.$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, $soap_request.$newLine);
        $buffer="";
        while($Response=fgets($Connect, 1024)){
            $buffer=$buffer.$Response;
        }
    } else die("Koneksi Gagal\n");

    print_r($buffer);
?>
```

the script is succeed and returning:

```
Contacting Machine...
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: ZK Web Server
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml
Connection: close


<GetAllUserInfoResponse>
<Row><PIN>1</PIN><Name>INDRA</Name><Password>1234</Password><Group>0</Group><Privilege>0</Privilege><Card>0</Card><PIN2>1</PIN2><TZ1>0</TZ1><TZ2>0</TZ2><TZ3>0</TZ3></Row>
</GetAllUserInfoResponse>
```

User INDRA has 2 Fingerprint recorded in the machine. Then I wrote getTemplate.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'config.php';
    include_once 'functions.php';

    echo "Contacting Machine...\n";

    $Connect = fsockopen(IP, "80", $errno, $errstr, 1);
    if($Connect) {
        $soap_request="<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><GetUserTemplate><ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">".KEY."</ArgComKey><Arg><PIN xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">1</PIN><FingerID xsi:type="xsd:integer”>1</FingerID></Arg></GetUserTemplate></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
        $newLine="\r\n";
        fputs($Connect, "POST /iWsService HTTP/1.0".$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, "Content-Type: text/xml".$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, "Content-Length: ".strlen($soap_request).$newLine.$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, $soap_request.$newLine);
        $buffer="";
        while($Response=fgets($Connect, 1024)){
            $buffer=$buffer.$Response;
        }
    } else die("Koneksi Gagal\n");

    print_r($buffer);
?>
```

the script is returning this:

```
Contacting Machine...
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: ZK Web Server
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<GetUserTemplateResponse>
</GetUserTemplateResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

is there any clue? i had tried to change FingerID from 0 - 2 but no result change.

Comment: Hello , can i know i can i enable telnet so i can connect to get data ? thanks ..

Comment: What is the type of ZK which support SOAP

Comment: Use FingerID = "ALL" and find the correct ID's recorded on device, you're probably using an unset ID.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong method. Change semantic tag GetUserTemplate into GetUserInfo.

```html
    <GetUserInfo>
        <ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">".$key."</ArgComKey>
        <Arg>
            <PIN xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">".$pin."</PIN>
        </Arg>
    </GetUserInfo>
```

You can change the $pin value into specific user pin to retrieve fingerprint data specific to that user or you can use ALL keyword to retrieve all user fingerprint data.

Comment: Can you link any documentation on the available commands in the ZK SOAP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone lands here again, here's a working sample:

```
<GetUserTemplate>
    <ArgComKey>0</ArgComKey>
    <Arg>
        <PIN>1</PIN>
        <FingerID>ALL</FingerID>
    </Arg>
</GetUserTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the ZK Soap PHP Library from [ZK Soap PHP Library](https://github.com/FAHRIZTX/ZKSoapPHP).

Just use:

```php
// reference the ZK Soap PHP namespace
use Fahriztx\Zksoapphp\Fingerprint;

// initial
$machine = Fingerprint::connect('192.168.1.175', '80', '123456');

// get machine status
echo "Machine Status : ".$machine->getStatus(); // connect | disconnect

// get all log data
print_r($machine->getAttendance()); // return Array of Attendance Log

// get all log data with date
print_r($machine->getAttendance('all', '2022-05-01')); // return Array of Attendance Log

// get all log data with date range
print_r($machine->getAttendance('all', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-10')); // return Array of Attendance Log

// get specific pin log data
print_r($machine->getAttendance(1)); // return Array of Attendance Log
// OR Array
print_r($machine->getAttendance([1, 2])); // return Array of Attendance Log
```

No need to write socket connection and xml payload.